# Git is not ignoring neither checking out .vs folder (VS2015)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

In my *.gitignore* file, there's a line to ignore the Visual Studio 2015 folder (".vs/"), but it's not being ignored.

And, besides, I can't use the *checkout* command. That's what was returned:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .vs/

PS C:\path\to\project> git checkout -- .vs/
error: pathspec '.vs/' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Please post your .gitignore file content.

Comment: Is the .vs folder already committed in Git?

Comment: @GregBurghardt If its already pushed to the repository can we not ignore .vs folder conetnts?

Answer (score 3):

Try below -

```
git rm -r .vs
```

then open `.gitignore` and add end of file

```
.vs/
```

This should work

Comment: Well, there was already a `.vs/` in the `.gitignore`, but anyway I tried what you've said and didn't worked. ):

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do have a `.gitignore` file at the same level (or above) of the `.vs` folder, and that it does contain `.vs/` (no extra space at the end of that line).

Try that same rule in a `subfolder/.vs` (where you would create a lest a file), to see if it does work there.

Comment: They were both on the base folder of the project. I tried to put the ".vs" folder on another directory, and the result was the same. But thank you!

Comment: @RafaelEscobar is there any extra space after `.vs/` in the .gitignore? Is the .gitignore *not* encoded in UT8  w/o BOM? (with unix end of lines)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the checkout problem, but I encountered the ".vs" problem today. It's because my .gitignore file was created in VS, therefore the file was encoded with UTF8 **with** BOM, and ".vs" was written on the first line. Since git cannot properly read the first line, ".vs" wouldn't work. Typical MS style... Just remove the BOM.

Comment: Worked for me - even if this wasn't on the first line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

## Your Problem

Your path should be `.vs\`

## The Problem

The syntax for .tfignore is not well understood.

#### The Other Problem

Visual Studio Websites (NOT projects), do not have the "**Exclude From Project**" option on the right-click context menu. This is where .tfignore comes very handy.

---

## .tfignore DOES WORK for VS2013 and VS2015

---

## The Rules

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx)

> 1. #  begins a comment line (omit single quotes)
> 2. The * and ? wildcards are supported.
> 3. A filespec is recursive unless prefixed by the \ character.
> 4. ! negates a filespec (files that match the pattern are not ignored)

---

## Examples

Given project structure: **myproject\subfoler\file.ext**

# Ignores all files in the folder and all sub-folders recursively

```
myproject\*.*
```

# Ignores **ONLY** files in the folder but **NOT** the sub-folders. Notice the beginning backslash \

```
\myproject\*.*
```

# Ignores all files **ONLY** in the sub-folder

```
\myproject\subfoler\*.*
```

# Ignores all files in this folder and all sub-folders. Does not ignore any file with extension .ext in the subfolder

```
myproject\*.*
!myproject\subfolder\*.ext
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be about `tfignore` (TFS) meanwhile OP is using `.gitignore` (git), and these have different semantics.

Comment: @jacobq thanks for the follow up. That was from 8 years ago, therefore it is probably outdate or irrelevant at this point.